# workflow not working when item updated

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have created a workflow on a list , SharePoint 2007, and attached it on item created and item updated. when creating an item, the workflow lunches, and in the workflow an update on the list item is done but the workflow is not lunching again, even when updating the item from code behind the workflow isn't lunching. what might be the problem.

Comment: Are there any relevant messages to be found in the Workflow History List? The Workflow History List can be found using the url http://[servername]/[sitename]/lists/Workflow%20History

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure that you are not firing the workflow using a System account. The System account can not run workflows. Have you tried restarting the timer service and closing and reopening SharePoint designer and republishing the workflow?

Another thing to check is whether you the item requires Check in / Check out, check the item in and see if the workflow runs...